# Position of .Take() has no effect on generated SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I've noticed that the position of `.Take()` has no effect on the resulting SQL. For example say I have this query:

```
IQueryable<Item> query = 
    db.Items.Where(i => i.CategoryID == categoryID && i.Deleted == false)
            .OrderByDescending(i => i.ItemID).Skip(0);
```

Then do the following two queries:

```
IQueryable<ItemViewModel> query1 = 
    query.Take(20).Select(i => new ItemViewModel { ItemID = i.ItemID });
IQueryable<ItemViewModel> query2 = 
    query.Select(i => new ItemViewModel { ItemID = i.ItemID }).Take(20);
```

Entity Framework will generate the following identical SQL for both queries:

```
SELECT TOP (20) 
  [Project1].[ItemID] AS [ItemID], 
FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[ItemID] AS [ItemID],
   row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[ItemID] DESC) AS [row_number]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Filter1].[ItemID] AS [ItemID], 
        FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[ItemID] AS [ItemID], 
    [Extent1].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID]
    FROM  [dbo].[Items] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE 0 = [Extent1].[Deleted] ) AS [Filter1]
        WHERE ([Filter1].[CategoryID] = @p__linq__0) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NOT NULL)
    )  AS [Project1]
)  AS [Project1]
WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Project1].[ItemID] DESC
```

Why does it do this? Shouldn't it instead generate the following for query1 with the `TOP 20` on the subquery?

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[ItemID] AS [ItemID]
    FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[ItemID] AS [ItemID]
        FROM ( SELECT TOP (20)
            [Extent1].[ItemID] AS [ItemID], 
            row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[ItemID] DESC) AS [row_number]
            FROM [dbo].[Items] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[CategoryID] = @p__linq__0) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NOT NULL)  
            AND (0 = [Extent1].[Deleted]) AND [Extent1].[row_number] > 0
            ORDER BY [Extent1].[ItemID] DESC
        )  AS [Project1]
    )  AS [Project1]
```

I noticed that moving `TOP 20` inside will increase the time from 7 seconds to an immediate response in my actual query since it doesn't do the projection before `TOP 20`.

Edit: Unfortunately I can't seem to find a way to force entity framework to do this since `query.Take(20).Select(i => new { ... }).ToString() == query.Select(i => new { .. }).Take(20).ToString()`. Maybe this is a bug in EF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the specific case that you mentioned, the two LINQ queries that you provided are functionally equivalent, in that the result set will always be the same, regardless of the ordering of `Take` and `Select`.

As for performance concerns, both queries will be optimized by the database platform.  I would be very surprised to see any significant difference between the two.  I would not expect the second query to, for example, perform the projection on a whole bunch of items it knows won't get past `TOP`.  As a rule LINQ query providers *tend* to not focus on optimization, simply because that step tends to happen at the database level when the SQL is translated into actual executable code.  Databases these days have spend a considerable amount of effort optimizing the compilation of SQL code, so the query provider simply has no need to duplicate those efforts.

However, when you have say filtering or ordering, it changes what the query actually returns.

```
query.Take(10).Where(someFilter);
```

doesn't (necessarily) return the same thing as:

```
query.Where(someFilter).Take(10);
```

The first takes 10 items and the returns however many of those items passes the filter.

The second query returns up to 10 items that all pass the filter.

In the case of the two SQL queries you showed, they *are functionally different* because one is ordering *every single item in the while table* and *then* grabbing 20 items, the other is grabbing the first 20 items and then ordering them, which is *much* faster of an operation.

In *that* case it's important for the semantic ordering of `Take` to be properly translated into the SQL.  In cases where the query provider can provably demonstrate that the order of two given operations isn't important, it's not a problem for it to re-order them however it wants.

Comment: The issue here is the `Select()`. I want the Take() to happen before the select. In my example I am always doing `query.Where(filter) ... .Take(10)`. For some reason `query.Select(r => new { .. }).Take(10)` is the same as `query.Take(10).Select(r => new { .. })`. I don't want the Select to be performed on the whole table by the SQL. In my database moving the `TOP` from the outside to the inside will reduce the query time from 7 seconds to an immediate result (in the actual query there is a lot going on inside the select).

Comment: @dhsto The select shouldn't be performed on the whole database if you're topping the results.  I'd suspect a problem with the query provider if that's the case, honestly.  If that fails to be optimized, for whatever reason, then that doesn't really leave you with much choice though, besides not using LINQ and writing the SQL yourself.

Comment: @dhsto Run the sql in Management Studio and take a look at the [Execution Plan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758912/how-to-read-an-execution-plan-in-sql-server). You will see the ordering that actually happens, this is the re-ordering the database engine performs on your behalf that Servy was talking about. Take a look at [this question of mine from the dba site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29884/execution-plan-flips-filter-and-execute-scalar-when-using-the-pk-causes-cast-to) where adding a `and` to the where clause was changing the execution plan and causing a casting error.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It's doing the TOP at the very end just like the SQL query is written by EF. If I write `query.Take(10).Select(r => new { ... })` then I would presume entity framework should know to write SQL to do the top `TOP 10` results before doing the projection, but unfortunately `query.Take(10).Select(r => new { ... }).ToString() == query.Select(r => new { ... }).Take(10).ToString()`. I guess the easiest thing for me to do right now is get all the entities, then do the projection in c# instead... unfortunately that's not ideal.

Comment: @dhsto It's not the responsibility of EF to make such an optimization.  It's the responsibility of the actual database.  I would fully expect it to perform such an optimization.  If it doesn't (and that really is quite shocking), then *that* is where the issue lies.

Comment: @Servy Wait, I don't think they are functionally equivalent. Moving the "top" to the inside of that subquery means that it's a top without an order. *That* is why the latter is faster: it's not correct, it's picking 20 rows at random rather than the latest 20 by itemId

Comment: @JohnGibb ah, I see what you're saying. I'm going to edit the query to do that properly and see the result (I think it will still be fast).

Comment: @Servy it makes sense to me why SQL Server would have to execute a subquery before being able to execute the surrounding queries. EF is writing the SQL in such a way that the ordering is done on the entire projection (I guess the optimization might be able to figure this out, but obviously not in this case). I think this is an EF performance issue.

Comment: @dhsto But it's not.  There's no reason why the SQL provider cannot optimize the query such that the projection is only performed on 20 of the items.  This is certainly an optimization that should be done on the DB, not by EF, as the given SQL queries are logically equivalent.

Comment: @Servy well one query runs in 7 seconds while the other runs in less than a second... so obviously there is some difference here. I'm just going to use jle's solution for now unfortunately.

Comment: @dhsto The point though is that it's your database failing to optimize the query, not EF.

Comment: @Servy ok, thanks for your help! It might have to do with the fact that my work runs SQL Server 2008 on their servers. Maybe the queries run identically on a more recent version. I doubt they'll be upgrading any time soon though :(

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually pretty simple. You're basically comparing these two queries:

```
select top 20 ItemId
from Items
order by ItemId desc
```

to:

```
select ItemId
from (
   select top 20 ItemId
   from Items
) p
order by ItemId descending
```

The latter will be picking twenty rows at random rather than the 20 rows with the highest `ItemIds`. *That* is why the query that you expected but didn't get is faster: it's incorrect and much simpler to run by the database.

Comment: When I moved the `TOP 20` into the generated SQL's sub query I forgot to also move the ORDER BY. In the actual C# code I'm doing the `.OrderByDescending()` before the `Take()`.

Comment: I agree you're not going to get the entity framework to put the `top` and the `order by` inside of the subquery, because it's equivalent and shouldn't matter where they go in this case. I highly doubt you'll see a difference in performance between the two approaches, once they are doing the same thing.

Comment: When I also move the `ORDER BY` into the generated subquery it still happens immediately. I don't think sorting on a primary key on the entire table is the issue. I think the issue is that the projection is done on the entire table in the subquery.

Comment: Sorry John, my original "what I think the DB should generate" was wrong. Regardless, what I think it should generate is still much faster and this answer is not correct.

Comment: That's crazy that it's still much faster, oh well! I guess there are always edge cases in the query optimizer, they really should have been the same (it shouldn't have performed the projection on the whole table regardless of how it was written). Anyway, glad you figured it out!

Comment: yeah, it's incredibly annoying haha